# JS instantiate an object on click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to instantiate my car object by clicking a create car button. This is what I have so far but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
$("#createCar").click(function(){
Car();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a constructor function called `Car`,

You can create a new instance using [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator:

```
$("#createCar").click(function(){
  var myCar = new Car();
});
```